# Knockout.js: call function on the prototype but stay in the context of the foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach, this

What I am trying to create is a basic Tic-Tac-Toe game using knockout.js. I am also using jade as a preprocessor; let me know if you are confused by it, but it should be pretty straight forward.

So I need to use a function on my objects in my foreach databind in my HTML, but I also need to have access to other objects in the viewModel. I am not quite sure how to do this. I can access the function if I put it on the objects in the foreach, but then I can't access objects outside of that object.

So my question is: How do I call a function from a foreach context that has access to everything on the viewModel?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
table.bg-success(style="table-layout:fixed;")
  tr#row1(data-bind="foreach:topRow")

    td(data-bind="text:symbol,click:function(){$parent.PlayerTurn.bind($root)();$root.changeSymbol()}")

  tr#row2(data-bind="foreach:middleRow")
    td(data-bind="text:symbol,click:function(){$parent.PlayerTurn.bind($root)();$root.changeSymbol()}") 

  tr#row3(data-bind="foreach:bottomRow")
    td(data-bind="text:symbol,click:function(){$parent.PlayerTurn.bind($root)();$root.changeSymbol()}")
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var aBox = (function(position){
  function ABox(){
    this.symbol = ko.observable("");
    this.position = position
    this.count = 0;

  }

  return ABox;
})()

var viewModel = (function(){
  function ViewModel(){
    this.theMessage = new message();
    this.thePlayers = new players();
    this.topRow = ko.observableArray([
      new aBox("r1c1"),
      new aBox("r1c2"),
      new aBox("r1c3"),     
    ]);
    this.middleRow = ko.observableArray([
      new aBox("r2c1"),
      new aBox("r2c2"),
      new aBox("r2c3"),
    ]);
    this.bottomRow = ko.observableArray([
      new aBox("r3c1"),
      new aBox("r3c2"),
      new aBox("r3c3"),
    ]);     
  }

    ViewModel.prototype.changeSymbol = function(){
      this.count+=1;
      if(this.count%2==0){
      this.symbol("O");
      }else{
        this.symbol("X")
      }
    }    

  return ViewModel;
})()

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

Comment: The click binding will pass the current context ($data) to its function. Don't use `this`. Use the passed parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess I am not sure what you mean. I tried changing "this.symbol" in the prototype to "$data.symbol." I also tried putting a parameter in the anonymous function that "changeSymbol" equals, and used that parameter inside the function with no luck. Could you be a little more descriptive for a ripe developer like me?

Comment: Actually, my problem was it was on the prototype, and I switched it to the viewModel object itself and it worked. Do you know why @RoyJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get into the habit of placing *all* logic in the view model / javascript, not in the view. Also, read through [the `click` binding handler documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) it actually answers most of your questions and is only a short read.

Basically, this:

```
td(data-bind="text:symbol, click: $root.changeSymbol")
```

Then you can have this function on `$root`:

```
var self = this;
self.changeSymbol = function(childVm) {
  console.log(self); // is the $root
  console.log(childVm); // the item from the foreach
}
```

If you need to access elements *between* the "child" and "root" (i.e. there lies a `$parent` in between) you should either:

- Move the `changeSymbol` function to `$parent` and make sure the parent view model has a reference to *its* parent if you need to use that inside the function; or
- Place a property for the parent on the child vm so that the function can call `childVm.parent` to get to that view model.

As a foot note, if you *absolutely have to*, you could do this:

```
td(data-bind="text:symbol, click: function() { $root.changeSymbol($root, $parent, $data); }")
```

But that probably means you have an XY-problem and your view models are not structured the way they should be.